# FECHA ACTUAL CON PHP

Tags: php

Hola a todos tengo un pequeño problema, lo que pasa es que tengo un input date pero no me mantiene la fecha actual hasta las 12 ; si no que me lo cambia a las 6:00 pm más o menos no me mantiene el día actual hasta las 12:00 pm como debería de ser, estoy trabajando en PHP

```
 <input type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" class="form-control" name="fecha_actual">
```

Comment: Es la zona horaria del servidor, se configura en __php.ini__

Answer (score 2):

Puedes cambiar el timezone de php para trabajar con el de tu país.

[Listado de zonas horarias admitidas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/El_Salvador');
$date = date('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Para que sea universal, sería mejor hacerlo desde el cliente con JavaSscript

Comment: ¿a qué te refieres con universal y que sería mejor @anythingg?

Comment: @BetaM que cualquier persona tenga la zona horaria de el país en que se encuentra, para eso es mejor hacerlo desde el cliente con Javascript

Comment: @anythingg, si correcto pero depende del contexto donde lo necesites no?

Comment: @JoséVásquez Entiendo, pero en este caso, el OP trata de poner la fecha actual en un _input_, no proporciona más contexto, por lo que desconocemos si quiere cambiar la hora universalmente para que sea una sola en el servidor o si quiere que sea distinta para cada localización

Comment: Pues por el momento solo esta para colombia aunque si seria bueno pensarlo universalmente, como podria hacerlo con javascript @JoséVásquez